# Python SQLalchemy package... if a database is on AWS, is it definitely Redshift?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I'm new to Python. I found a sample database from DataCamp, and I'm able to easily connect in Microsoft's Azure Data Studio ( I use a Mac so this is the closest thing to SSMS)
I tried to use the SQLalchemy package to connect within Python, because that is the package they teach you to use in DataCamp's Python tutorial, but I'm having trouble understanding how to go about it, because it doesn't seem as easy as it was in their tutorial. 
The thing is, it looks like I need to choose a specific "Dialect" to properly connect, depending on what kind of SQL server it is. Since this database is at amazonaws.com, is it safe to assume this is a Redshift db? If not, how do I know which dialect to download?
I pasted the database info at the bottom.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html

Database: ec2-52-14-205-70.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

(source: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sql-tableau )

Comment: You don't (usually) download the dialects; they come with the SQLA package. You do need to download a DB-API driver though, such as pymssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if a database is on AWS, is it definitely Redshift?

No. Amazon offers a [wide range](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/) of database services. However the fact that it's on a *.amazonaws.com domain name does not tell you if it's one of these (it might be a virtual machine, either Linux or Windows, running some database you have never heard of).

In this case you reference the datacamp article which says:

> Server Name: ec2-52-14-205-70.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> Authentication: SQL Server Authentication

Based upon the authentication type this is a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have verified this by connecting to it using Microsoft SQL Server Managemnt Studio (and its "Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit)" v14.0.1000.169).